# Como detectar se a requisição $http é uma resposta cache ou não?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No AngularJs, o `$http` tem uma opção muito útil de cachear o resultado de uma requisição a uma `url` específica.

Por exemplo:

```
 $scope.getUsers = function () {
       return $http.get('/users', {cache: true})
 }

 $scope.getUsers().then( response => console.log(response.data)); // Faz a requisição

 $scope.getUsers().then( response => console.log(response.data)); // Pega o cache, pois foi feita uma primeira requisição
```

Porém agora me surgiu uma pequena necessidade: Gostaria de saber, quando recebo uma resposta, se aquela resposta veio de um cache ou não, e não achei nada na variável `response` (que é retornada no parâmetro `then`) que indice isso.

Existe alguma forma no AngularJS de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Não acredito que seja possível, pelo menos não com o `$cacheFactory` padrão. Voc~e pode vir a utilizar esta lib [`angular-cache`](http://www.pseudobry.com/angular-cache/), basicamente ela substitui o `$cacheFactory` com uma serie de extras.

Uma outra opção, é não utilizar o `{ cache: true }` e gerenciar manualmente o seu `cache`, segue um exemplo de `slide expiration`:

```
const timeout = 300; // 5 minutos
const cache = $cacheFactory('myCache');

...

let cacheKey = 'e024ecb7-f916-4870-b839-568286659671'
let data = cache.get(cacheKey);
let requestApi = (resolve, reject) => {
    $http.get(url).success(function(result) {
        cache.put(cacheKey, { 
            object: result,
            date: new Date()
        });
        resolve(result);
    });
}
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!data) {
        requestApi(resolve, reject)
    } else {
        var date = new Date();
        var ellapsed = (date - data.date) / 1000
        if (date > timeout) {
            cache.remove(cacheKey);
            requestApi(resolve, reject);
        } else {
            data.date = new Date()
            cache.put(data);
            resolve(data.object);
        }
    }
})
```